# Syntax error on token "::", invalid AssignmentOperator when groupingBy

Tags: lambda, java-8, functional-programming, stream

I have this class:

```
public class MenuPrice {


    private BigDecimal price;


    private Date updateDate;


}
```

I want to group by Date,

```
List<MenuPrice> menuPrices = findAll(restaurant);

menuPrices
                .parallelStream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MenuPrice::getUpdateDate()));
```

but I have a compilation error : **Syntax error on token "::", invalid 
 AssignmentOperator**

Comment: Drop the parentheses after the method reference. Also, create that unexisting method, don't use a parallel stream, and use java.time classes instea of the old Date class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple syntax problem you are having here:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MenuPrice::getUpdateDate));
```

But, I've seen that in other questions you (ab)use `parallel` in streams. This is most probably never a good idea, as you usually require *lots* of data for parallel to have any relevance.

Than using `java.util.Date` raises questions too; it's a really old API... This is especially weird since you use java-8 for streaming, but it already comes with far better classes in the `java.time` package